# Setting default value for a timebox

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-mobile, datebox

I am using the Datebox(timebox mode) jquerymobile plugin in my Rails app to choose some hours. I am trying to set the default value by using defaultPickerValue, but I dont how to add it.

I can only find this document about it
http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox1/demos/api/matrix.html#&ui-page=1-2

I have tried a lot variations like this:

```
 <%= builder.text_field :start_time, "data-role" => "datebox", "data-options" => '{"mode": "timebox", "minuteStep": 15, "defaultPickerValue": "[12,0]" }'  %>
```

and

```
<%= builder.text_field :end_time, "data-role" => "datebox", "defaultPickerValue" => "[12,0]",  "data-options" => '{"mode": "timebox", "minuteStep":15 }'%>
```

Is it only possible to set by script on on load?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it whenever you want.

Take a look at this example:

```
var defaultPickerValue = [12, 0, 0]; // 12 hour, 0 minutes, 0 seconds
$('#datePickerID').data('timebox').options.defaultPickerValue = defaultPickerValue;
```

Use this format to set any other needed option.

Or better do it like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/3x5PZ/8/). It is an easier solution.

Comment: Aye - indeed, it must be a 3 element array - I'm sure I had a good reason for that, but if you include seconds, all should work.

Comment: I could not get     $('#datePickerID').data('timebox').options.defaultPickerValue = defaultPickerValue  to work. I had to use     $('#datePickerID').data('datebox').options.defaultPickerValue = defaultPickerValue